# Reading XML File in vb.net - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

I have a series of XML files which are formatted the same. I need to parse through and extract values for certain tags. Here is my vb code (Error is noted):

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim newRow As DataRow
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    doc.Load(TextBox1.Text)

    dt.Columns.Add("")
    dt.Columns.Add("")
    dt.Columns.Add("")
    dt.Columns.Add("")

    For Each n As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("LOG/TYPE")

        newRow = dt.NewRow
        newRow(n.Attributes("EVT").Value) = n.InnerText '-> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

    Next

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Here is the layout of the XML file I am trying to parse:

```
<LOG>
  <TYPE>
    <CLASS>class</CLASS> 
    <CODE>code</CODE> 
    <EVT>evt</EVT> 
    <SEVERITY>sev</SEVERITY> 
    <LABEL>label</LABEL> 
    <ORIGIN>origin</ORIGIN> 
    <USERNUMBER>user</USERNUMBER> 
    <USERTEXT>text</USERTEXT> 
  </TYPE>
  <TYPE>
    <CLASS>class1</CLASS> 
    <CODE>code1</CODE> 
    <EVT>evt1</EVT> 
    <SEVERITY>sev1</SEVERITY> 
    <LABEL>label1</LABEL> 
    <ORIGIN>origin1</ORIGIN> 
    <USERNUMBER>user1</USERNUMBER> 
    <USERTEXT>text1</USERTEXT> 
  </TYPE>
</LOG>
```

The tag values I need for each datagrid row are as follows:

```
<EVT>
<SEVERITY>
<LABEL>
<ORIGIN>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `dt.Rows.Add(newRow)` before `Next`.

Comment: I see that, I added. The issue is with the newRow(n.Attributes("EVT").Value) = n.InnerText '-> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Change `newRow(n.Attributes("EVT").Value) = n.InnerText` to `newRow.Item("EVT") = n.Item("EVT").Value`. Assuming you have added a DataColumn named "EVT" to the DataTable.

Comment: BTW, this might be of some interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That gets past the Object Reference error and now produces the datagrid. However doesnt provide the value from EVT tag (evt, evt1)

Comment: Try change `n.Item("EVT").Value` to `n.Item("EVT").InnerText`

Comment: I used different method from link you sent...I will upload soon